# How to create symlink from public/storage to storage/app/public in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I have no idea on how to create **symbolic link** or **symlink**.

I am working on File system in laravel 5.2.

The document says that i need to create a **symbolic link** from **public/storage** to **storage/app/public** to keep the publicly accessible files in one directory.

How to create that symlink or symbolic link?

Which file or directory should I place that code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
App::make('files')->link(storage_path('app/public'), public_path('storage'));
```

And don't forget to use **App** after namespace.

Comment: where (which file) should I insert this line of code into?

Comment: Service provider or Controller. As your wish

Answer (score 5):

Run this command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Answer (score 2):

In a Windows environment, you can:

1. `cmd` with *Run as administrator*
2. Run the [`mklink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) command:

```
mklink /D "C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxx\yyy\public\storage\" 
"C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxx\xxx\storage\public\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Added same code but still getting issue.
Method link does not exist.
currently i am adding link in my controller constructor.

here is code:

```
       public function index()
  {
     $shots=[];
      App::make('files')->link(storage_path('app\public'), public_path('..\public\storage'));
     return View::make('adminpages.index',['shots'=>$shots]);
   }
```

[image]

Comment: You forgot to add "\" before the App like this:


\App::make('files')->link(storage_path('app/public'), public_path('storage'));

        return view('admin.schoolsettings');

Answer (score 0):

On Shared Server, where one doesn't have ssh access to run
`php artisan storage:link` this helps me run that from a controller, the if block code section can also be placed in a Service Provider as well as suggested by @shìpu-ahamed

```
public function displayForm()
{

        if(!file_exists(public_path('storage'))) {
           \App::make('files')->link(storage_path('app/public'), public_path('storage'));
    }
        return view('admin.index');
}
```