# Laravel Storage not syncing with public Storage folder

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

When I was working locally I could save files in a storage and they would automatically appear in `public/storage` directory. Now I've transferred the same project to a shared server, but the storage doesn't seem to be in sync with `public/storage` directory.

This is how I store a file:

```
$path = 'app/public/images';
$img->save(storage_path($path.'/photo.jpg'));
```

And this is how I retrieve it:

```
Storage::url('public/images/photo.jpg);
```

NB: I linked the storage using `php artisan storage:link` locally, I don't know if I need to do that again (which may prove to be difficult if possible because I'm on a shared host) now that I'm on a different server or not.

Comment: You should be able to create the symlink between the folders as you have stated in your question. if this fails, please let us know of any errors

`php artisan storage:link`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was to symlink the storage directory. However, I couldn't use `php artisan storage:link` because my host doesn't support SSH. Instead I used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38045119/how-to-create-symlink-from-public-storage-to-storage-app-public-in-laravel).

Answer (score 0):

I deployed some projects on shared hosting, and i found the same error, and the issue with store images with path is bacause the index root is different in share hosting. You can fix like this:

```
$my_public = 'home/username/public_thml/your_project_laravel/'
$path = 'app/public/images';
$img->save($my_public.$path.'/photo.jpg'));
```

You need specifc the path of your share hosting, other way is change the root of public html in your share hosting but it will change all the references paths in your account, if you have other websites in the same hosting is not a good solution.