# Files not synchronizing between storage and public folder

Tags: linux, laravel, file-upload

I'm trying to make files stored in the **app/storage/public** folder accessible from the public folder but I'm hitting an issue.

I came across this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38045119/how-to-create-symlink-from-public-storage-to-storage-app-public-in-laravel) but It's not clear enough as to where  I need to add to that code.  I also did `php artisan storage:link` but it's not working.  The strange thing is that I works fine on my windows machine, however when I move the application to linux, it doesn't work. it gives a 404 error.  I've also taken note of the following:

- The files are successfully stored in the storage folder,
- The files are not accessible in the storage folder.

[image]

On the left, its the public folder, and on the right its the storage folder.  All matching files that are successfully showing in the public folder where uploaded when the application was on the windows machine, while the additional two files that failed to sync to public folder were uploaded when the application was on the linux machine

Comment: What does your public folder shows? it should contain `uploads` as a symlink to `storage/app/public`

Comment: @MajedDH The public folder had a folder called storage, and the files previously uploaded when the application was on a windows machine. Files uploaded from after deployment to linux don't sync to the public folder

Comment: It's not syncing, it's a shortcut to the storage folder. Since you think it's syncing then I think `uploads`  in your public folder is not a symlink, it's an actual folder. to repair that delete or rename `public/uploads` and re-execute `php artisan storage:link`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete storage in public folder then run `php artisan storage:link`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not syncing, it's a shortcut to the storage folder. Since you think it's syncing then I think `uploads` in your public folder is not a symlink, it's an actual folder. to repair that delete or rename `public/uploads` and re-execute `php artisan storage:link`